# Laravel Creating a record with a foreign key that points to reference table

Tags: database, laravel, controller, foreign-keys, one-to-one

I have a somewhat simple questions about how to correctly reference a table for a foreign key. So In have two tables, a Transaction table, and an Transaction Source table. Now the relationship between these two tables is One to One, also their are only three values used in the Transaction Source for now, "Vendor", "Sponsor", and "Participant". I have a foreign key in the Transaction table that I would like to reference the Transaction Source table to get one of these values when I create a new record. now my question is how would I go about doing this in the controller environment when creating a new model object, could i simply associate the ID from Transaction Source to the Foreign key in my Transaction table, or is there another method of achieving what I asking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe transaction source has autoincrement row

In transaction table migration add

```
$table->integer('transaction_source_id')->nullable()->index();
$table->foreign('transaction_source_id')->references('id')->on('transaction_sources');
```

Please use relevant table names in your migration.

Its a good practice to use

```
$table->integer('id', true);
```

instead of

```
$table->increments('id');
```

Now when adding transaction just use the transaction source id.

Reference
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i have something similar to this, and i believe you are correct about the Integer, instead of the Increments, but in the controller how would this be tied together, for example how would i tie one of the sources to a transaction without create a new record in the sources table, sort of like a enum